# javascript insert after every digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add a space after every occurrence of a digit with javascript.

`"2tim"` will be `"2 tim"`

js

```
var v = '2tim';
v.replace(/(\d+)/, /\1 /);
```

Comment: What should `22tim` look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 things wrong with your code:

1. The second argument to `replace` should be a string.
2. To use a captured group, use the dollar sign.
3. You don't want to capture all digits into the same group (`\d+`). Just capture one digit, and make the regex global.

```js
var v = '2tim';
v = v.replace(/(\d)/g, '$1 ');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qujsq/

---

If you want to add a space only after a group of digits, then *do* use a `+`:

```
var v = '12times';
v = v.replace(/(\d+)/g, '$1 ');
```